# Modify only part of object properties

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a class structure like this:

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Details")]
public class Details
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Size")]
    public string Size { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Length")]
    public string Length { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Notes")]
public class Notes
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Text")]
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "Data")]
public class Data
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "ID")]
    public string ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "FileName")]
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
    public string Status { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Date")]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Details")]
    public Details Details { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Notes")]
    public Notes Notes { get; set; }
}

[XmlRoot(ElementName = "AllData")]
public class AllData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Data")]
    public Data[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

I have a requirement where in I would like to update only a part of this class eg. update Data(Name, fileName, Status, Details etc.) where id=1 and then write the whole AllData properties to an xml file.

I am reading the data from an XML file using XML serializer and displaying it in text boxes where user is allowed to modify the data. Once user modifies the data it has to put back to same XMl file.

I tried to do it using linq but not getting it correctly.

This is returning all the relevant data I would like to modify.

```
Data data= new Data();
data = (from data in AllData.data
      where data.ID == "1"
      select data).FirstOrDefault();
```

Now I want to modify data only where ID=1:
something like this:

```
var query = (from records in recordings.Record
             where records.ID == "1"
             select records).Select(x => { x.Name = "foo"; return x; }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

LinQ means *L*anguage *in*tegrated ***q*uery**. It's for querying data, not manipulating it.

You selected the data you want to manipulate:

```
var data = (from data in AllData.data where data.ID == "1" select data).ToList();
```

Personally, I prefer the method syntax, but it's the same really:

```
var data = AllData.data.Where(data => data.ID == "1").ToList();
```

Now that you have the data, you need to manipulate it. In the old fashioned way:

```
foreach(var d in data)
{
    d.Name = "foo";
}
```

Now your data is changed. You might want to display the changes or write them to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working with `C#` classes you could simply serialize those object back to `Xml`, not quite sure why you want to deal with `Xml` directly.

You could use `XmlSerializer` to serialize your `Xml` and save the file.

```
 XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(AllData));
 using(StringWriter sww = new StringWriter())
 using(XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(sww))
 {
     serializer.Serialize(writer, alldata); // your object
     var xml = sww.ToString(); // your xml.
     // save your xml
 }
```